# get a variable number of columns for output in sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf

Is there a way to get a variable number of columns for a given predicate? Essentially, I want to turn this:

```
title note
A.    1
A.    2
A.    3
B.   4
B.   5
```

into

```
title note1 note2 note3
A.    1     2     3
B.    4     5     null
```

Like, can i set the columns created to the maximum number of "notes" in the query or something. Thanks.

Comment: You’ll probably need to post-process because I think those two representations mean different things sparql-wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can approach this. One way is to change your query. Now, in the general case it is not possible to do a SELECT query that does exactly what you want. However, if you happen to know in advance what the maximum number of notes per title is, you can sort of do this.

Supposing your original query was something like this:

```
SELECT ?title ?note
WHERE { ?title :hasNote ?note }
```

And supposing you know titles have at most 3 notes, you could *probably* (untested) do something like this:

```
SELECT ?title ?note1 ?note2 ?note3
WHERE { 
        ?title :hasNote ?note1 .
        OPTIONAL { ?title :hasNote ?note2 . FILTER (?note2 != ?note1) }
        OPTIONAL { ?title :hasNote ?note3 . FILTER (?note3 != ?note1 && ?note3 != ?note2) }
}
```

As you can see this is not a very nice solution though: it doesn't scale and is probably very inefficient to process as well.

Alternatives are various forms of post-processing. To make it simpler to post-process you could use an aggregate operator to get all notes for a single item on a single line at least:

```
SELECT ?title (GROUP_CONCAT(?note) as ?notes) 
WHERE { ?title :hasNote ?note }
GROUP BY ?title
```

result:

```
title notes
A.    "1 2 3"
B.    "4 5"
```

You could then post-process the values of the `?notes` variable to split them into the separate notes again.

Another solution is that instead of using a SELECT query, you use a CONSTRUCT query to give you back an RDF graph, rather than a table, and work directly with that in your code. Tables are kinda weird in an RDF world if you think about it: you're querying a graph model, why is the query result not a graph but a table?

```
CONSTRUCT
WHERE { ?title :hasNote ?note }
```

...and then process the result in whatever API you're using to do the queries.

Comment: Thanks for the notes! This helps a lot The issue is that I need a table for reporting, but your second idea is interesting. I will give it a shot!